# Verificar status http no angular

Tags: angular, http

Tenho o seguinte código, preciso verificar o status que o servidor retorna para o WebApp, tenho o seguinte código:

```
this.http.post (this.url,json) 

    .subscribe ( 
          res => { 
            console.log(res);
          }, 
          (err: any) => { 
            console.log('raw error =>', err);
          } 
        );}
```

Comment: Qual a versão do Angular? As mais recentes ( >6) tem um uso diferente pra pegar o status do retorno

Comment: Talvez isso lhe interesse: [HttpClient - Getting error details](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz assim:

```
this.http.post (this.url,json, {observe: 'response'})     
    .subscribe ( 
          res => { 
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.status);
          }, 
          (err: any) => { 
            console.log('raw error =>', err);
          } 
        );}
```

Comment: esta dando erro na parte {observe: 'response'}, por que?

Comment: Tenta no contructor(http:HttpClient)

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo. Deu certo.

Comment: Marca a resposta como certa! Valeu!